# Assigning custom foreign keys to Rails Junction table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, foreign-keys

I have a database where many 'posts' can have many 'tags'. I have a junction table set up in between posts and tags called 'post_tag'
However the names of the columns for the foreign keys of posts and tags are different in post_tag.

This is what i have in the post_tag model:

```
class PostTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "post_tag"

  #defining columns in post_tag that are foreign keys for post and tag tables
  belongs_to :post, :class_name => "Post", :foreign_key => "post_fk"
  belongs_to :tag, :class_name => "Tag", :foreign_key => "tag_fk"
end
```

`:foreign_key` is the name of the foreign key column in my post_tag junction table.In post_tag these foreign key fields equal the primary key in the post or tag table.
Here's the error I get:

```
irb(main):001:0> p = post.find(1)
irb(main):002:0> p.post_tags
      PostTag Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `post_tag`.* FROM `post_tag` WHERE `post_tag`.`post_id` = 1
    Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'post_tag.post_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `post_tag`.* FROM `post_tag` WHERE `post_tag`.`post_id` = 1
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'post_tag.post_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `post_tag`.* FROM `post_tag` WHERE `post_tag`.`post_id` = 1
```

How do I get it to stop looking for `post_id` but for `post_fk`??

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `:foreign_key => "actual_foreign_key"` is depreciated.

Should be using `foreign_key: "actual_foreign_key"` instead!